# Predicate<T> method equals()

Tags: java, guava

I'm using the interface `Predicate<T>` from `com.google.common.base` (Google Guava)

But I don't know how to have the `equals()` method works...

Why do I get `false` when I type something like this :

```
    Predicate<Object> PredicateD = new Predicate<Object>(){
          @Override public boolean apply(Object number) {
                return ((number instanceof Double) && (Math.floor((Double)number) == (Double)number));
            }    
    };

    Predicate<Object> PredicateM = new Predicate<Object>(){
          @Override public boolean apply(Object number) {
                return ((number instanceof Double) && (Math.floor((Double)number) == (Double)number));
            }    
    };

    System.out.println(PredicateD.equals(PredicateM));
```

Thanks in advance for your Help,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're creating two different anonymous inner classes, but neither of them is overriding `equals`, so you'll get the default implementation, whereby any two non-equal *references* are considered non-equal.

As the values of `PredicateD` and `PredicateM` are different references, `equals` returns false.

Comment: Can you show me on this example how do I need to override equals to get the result return True ?

Comment: @user757202: You really wouldn't be able to (using your current anonymous inner classes) without *insane* amounts of analysis to indicate that the code within the `apply` methods in both cases is equivalent. What are you really trying to achieve? What's the bigger picture?

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to implement basic set theory. The set A was defined as a predicate: (if Predicate.apply(x) then x is in A). I need the equal property to order different element of the class 'set'. I guess I cannot use the interface predicate for this purpose.

Comment: @user757202: Ordering shouldn't be done based on *equality* anyway - it can only give true/false rather than less/equal/greater answers. Generally speaking, detecting whether two predicates are equal is fundamentally hard.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try to do this another way.I was thinking of a simple inclusion problem, and I was just using the fact that  intersection between A and B equals B if and only if B is a subset of A.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this to print `true`, you would have to override the equals method on these classes. Your custom equals would have to check if the parameter is an instance of either of these classes. Since they are anonymous, you'd have no way of referencing them, so you can't really do that.

My suggestion would be to make a non-anonymous class (say, `IntegerCheckingPredicate`), and make `predicateD` and `predicateM` instances of that class. Then your equals method might look like:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof IntegerCheckPredicate) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then this test would pass:

```
@Test
public void testPredicatesWithEqualsOverriddenAreEqual() {
    IntegerCheckPredicate predicateM = new IntegerCheckPredicate();
    IntegerCheckPredicate predicateD = new IntegerCheckPredicate();
    assertEquals(predicateM, predicateD);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's necessary to override equals(). Predicate is functional class. The `Object.equals(){return (this == obj);}` is reasonable.